# Search and replace with commit in bitbucket multiple repositories

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

Is there a way to search and replace some string in Bitbucket git repositories under some project using Bitbucket administration tools/API/UI? The modification should be via git commit.

The only way that pops to mind is building some script which will go over all repositories.

Comment: What you're describing would be an *extremely* dangerous tool, there's nothing like it built into Bitbucket or any other SCM hosting system, and I doubt there ever will be (it's not an unreasonable use case, but as I'm sure you can imagine it would be a supportability nightmare). You'd need to write a script that would list all repos for a given project, clone them all, perform a find-and-replace across all text files in the repo, commit and push back up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do just such an operation. When we migrated from svn to git, we had to change the scm developerConnection in our pom.xml:

```
<developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:codehaus-plexus/plexus-interpolation.git</developerConnection>
```

in all our git repos from the svn developer connection to the git one. Here is the script I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import stashy
import os
import sys
import urllib2
import json
import base64
import getpass
from git import Repo
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from lxml import etree
import itertools
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
bitbucketBaseUrl = "https://bitbucket.company.com"
bitbucketUserName = "admin"


class BitBucketRepo:
    def __init__(self, name, repoUrl):
        self.name = name
        self.repoUrl = repoUrl


class CommentedTreeBuilder(ET.TreeBuilder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentedTreeBuilder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def comment(self, data):
        self.start(ET.Comment, {})
        self.data(data)
        self.end(ET.Comment)


def insert(originalfile, string):
    with open(originalfile, 'r') as f:
        with open('pom.xml.bak', 'w') as f2:
            f2.write(string + "\n")
            f2.write(f.read())
    os.rename('pom.xml.bak', originalfile)


def validateScriptParameters():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit("Usage: {} [Bit Bucket Module Project key, e.g. mf for Modules - Framework] [Bit Bucket admin password]".format(
            os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])))


def cloneRepo(repository):
    logging.info("Cloning repo [{}]".format(repository.repoUrl))
    repo = Repo.clone_from(repository.repoUrl, repository.name)
    return repo


def updatePomFile(repository):
    resultCode = 1
    ET.register_namespace('xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    ET.register_namespace('', "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0")
    cparser = ET.XMLParser(target = CommentedTreeBuilder())
    if os.path.isfile(os.getcwd() + "/" + repository.name + "/pom.xml"):
        tree = ET.parse(repository.name + "/pom.xml", parser=cparser)
        root = tree.getroot()

        ns = {'nodes': 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'}

        for scm in root.findall('nodes:scm', ns):
            if scm is not None:
                developerConnection = scm.find('nodes:developerConnection', ns)
                scm.remove(developerConnection)
                newDeveloperConnectionElm = Element("developerConnection")
                newDeveloperConnectionElm.tail = "\n\t"
                newDeveloperConnectionElm.text = str("scm:git:" + repository.repoUrl)
                scm.append(newDeveloperConnectionElm)
                resultCode = 0
            else:
                resultCode = 1

        if resultCode == 0:
            logging.info("Updating repository: " + repository.name)
            tree.write(repository.name + "/pom.xml")

    return resultCode


def updateRepo(bitbucket, projectKey):
    xmlVersion = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    repoList = bitbucket.projects[projectKey].repos

    for repoItem in repoList:
        cloneUrl = repoItem['links']['clone'][1]['href']

        if cloneUrl.startswith("http"):
           cloneUrl = repoItem['links']['clone'][0]['href']
        if not cloneUrl.startswith("ssh"):
           logging.error("Unable to retrieve valid clone url [{}], exiting...".format(cloneUrl))
           sys.exit(1)

        repository = BitBucketRepo(repoItem['name'], cloneUrl)
        clonedRepo = cloneRepo(repository)
        resultCode = updatePomFile(repository)
        if resultCode == 0:
             insert(repository.name + "/pom.xml", xmlVersion)
             clonedRepo.index.add([os.getcwd() + "/" + repository.name + "/pom.xml"])
             clonedRepo.index.commit("CM-8991: Updating pom.xml to use git connection string instead of svn")
             clonedRepo.remotes.origin.push()


validateScriptParameters()
logging.info('Bit Bucket URL [' + bitbucketBaseUrl + ']')
logging.info('User name [' + bitbucketUserName + ']')

projectKey = sys.argv[1]
bitbucketPassword = sys.argv[2]

bitbucket = stashy.connect(bitbucketBaseUrl, bitbucketUserName, bitbucketPassword)
logging.info("Module project key: [{}]".format(projectKey))

updateRepo(bitbucket, projectKey)
```

Note that it requires the 'stashy' python library, and is written for python2.